# DQL documentum like pattern with field

Tags: sql-like, dql, documentum

i tried to use field in like pattern but without success
this is my dql i tried:

```
select object_name from categories a, (select object_name from clients where client_number = '12345') d
where a.r_folder_path like '%'||d.object_name||'%'
```

actually i try to get all categories in the clients folder where client_number is 12345

i have not cabinet name to use `FOLDER` and not id to use `FOLDER(ID())` i have only client number.

tnx a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try using the concat function

```
SELECT 
    object_name 
FROM 
    categories a, (select object_name from clients where client_number = '12345') d
WHERE 
    a.r_folder_path LIKE CONCAT('%', d.object_name, '%')
```